# How to get hidden files and folders name and show it in a listbox control

Tags: vb.net, cmd, command-prompt

i'd like to show result of search hidden file/folder in directory computer. 
Command in command prompt for show file/folder hidden like this
 "shell ("dir/ah")".

And now i have problem ? How can i do these code to vb.net with result showing in listboxt vb.net ?

Comment: I guess `Directory.GetFiles()` will returns all the files including hidden ones also, Just try it `Dim directory As New DirectoryInfo("D:\FolderName")
Dim files As FileInfo() = directory.GetFiles()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through each file in the given path. If it has the attribute of hidden then add it to the list. At the end assign it to the datasource of your ListBox

```
Dim myHiddenFileList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
Dim thePath As String = "Some Directory Path"
' Iterate through file in directory thePath
For Each f In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(thePath)
Dim fileAttributes As FileAttributes = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(f).Attributes
If Not fileAttributes Is Nothing AndAlso fileAttributes = FileAttributes.Hidden Then
myHiddenFileList.Add(f) ' It is hidden so add to the list
End If
Next

myListBox.DataSource = myHiddenFileList ' myListBox is a list box already defined on the form.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim directory As New DirectoryInfo("D:\Apps\Hidden")
Dim hidden_Files As FileInfo() = directory.GetFiles(). _
                                 Where(Function(file) (file.Attributes And FileAttributes.Hidden) <> 0).ToArray()

Dim hidden_folders As DirectoryInfo() = directory.GetDirectories(). _
                                        Where(Function(dirs) (dirs.Attributes And FileAttributes.Hidden) <> 0).ToArray()
```

And you can add them to a `ListBox` control like below(*you can use your logic instead of this*):

```
 lstHiddenItems.Items().Add("--FILES--")
 For Each itm In hidden_Files
     lstHiddenItems.Items.Add(itm.Name)
 Next
     lstHiddenItems.Items().Add("")
     lstHiddenItems.Items().Add("--FOLDERS--")
 For Each itm In hidden_folders
     lstHiddenItems.Items.Add(itm.Name)
 Next
```

---

Result

[image]

Comment: thank's before. but i wanna put checkbox for select directory, so user can select anything directory . how can i do that?

Comment: Dim directory As New DirectoryInfo("D:\Apps\Hidden"). i want directory D:\apps\hidden can changes to another directory by checkbox or listbox.

Comment: So you've to first load directories path to checkbox or listbox